# Get first record of each entity order by a column

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a query in linq that fetch students assessments data something like

```
new {x.StudentId, x.StudentAssessmentId, x.AssessmentName, x.SubmittedDate}
```

then I perform some operations on this list to get only last added student assessment per student, I get last studentassessment by finding the max id of studentassessment,

so I finally get last studentassessments data of all the students.

Is there a way to do this directly in the initial list?

I thought about the way to group the results by student Id and select max of studentassessmentid, like

```
group x.StudentAssessmentId by x.StudentId
select new {x.Key, x.Max()}
```

in this way I will get student with there last studentassessmentid which is what I want but this will only give me studentassessment ids while I want other data also like AssessmentName, SubmittedDate etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
group x.StudentAssessmentId     
by new {
        x.StudentId, 
        x.AssessmentName,
        x.SubmittedDate } 
into g
select new 
{
  g.Key.StudentId, 
  g.Key.AssessmentName, 
  g.Key.SubmittedDate,
  g.Max(),
}
```